# Using Specflow and NUnit version 3 to run tests in paralel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, nunit, specflow

I have a project using SpecFlow and NUnit 2.6.3 as my test provider. Currently it is working OK but now there is the requirement to run tests in parallel, as they become more and more heavy.

Reading along, I can see that NUnit version 3 will support parallelism out of the box, but it is still in alpha. And I am unable to run the tests generated by SpecFlow with Nunit 3..

Does any one have an idea if it is possible to use SpecFlow and NUnit version 3 by this moment? Or some other approach, still using NUnit version 2.6.3 and SpecFlow for achieving parallelism?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you doing that is so "heavy"?  I'm guessing these aren't unit test.  Selenium by any chance?

Comment: yes, Specflow is generating the nUnit tests which then deal with selenium drivers for different browsers. There are couple of different browsers for couple of different environments, and the combinations produced out of them is becomming more and more heavy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the suggestions.

I come out with own custom solution - just exploring the test dll with reflection from a custom command line app which then spawns separate OS processes each of them calling nunit-console.exe with the --include parameter specifying only a particular group of tests. This way I avoid any thread unsafely code and still achieving my goal.

**Edit**

Btw, [here is my solution](https://bitbucket.org/akrsmv/parallel-tests), I hope someone may find it useful. Even though now there is builtin parallelism in nunit 3+, this was battle tested against thousands of specflow / selenium tests. It also has a nice TeamCity integration. I think its simple enough (3-4 classes in total) and I tried to document all the console options available in the `README` file

Comment: You mention this is built into nunit 3+. Do you know if Specflow supports parallel scenarios *within* a feature file? I've found a few references around the net indicating that it should be possible, but no concrete examples. All the concrete examples are around running separate features in parallel.

Comment: To answer my own question - it looks like nunit doesn't support this. Using the 'parallelization per method' attribute throws compilation errors.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same situation. I came up with a solution using Selenium Grid, the task parallel library and the DynamicObject class. I wrote about it here http://blog.dmbcllc.com/running-selenium-in-parallel-with-any-net-unit-testing-tool/. (Too long to copy and paste). Hope it helps.  As far as I know, until 3 releases, this is the best we can do.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested parallel test case execution at fixture level with NUnit 3.2.0. As of writing, SpecFlow 2.0 does support parallelism and is working well with NUnit 3.2.0, however SpecFlow reporting engine is not able to produce HTML reports from NUnit test execution output. The [issue is being tracked here over GitHub](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/539)